# field declared void / struct or variable not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I've been teaching myself some OpenGL using SFML for creating windows/handling inputs, etc. My main.cpp started getting a bit unwieldy so I decided to start splitting my code up. I created a 4X_vertex.h and a 4X_vertex.cpp (4X is the name of the project) and moved the relevant functions and structs out of my main and into these files. However, when I compile, I get the error

```
variable or field "drawVertexArray" declared void
```

which from my research seems to be just an unhelpful message relating to the next error, which is

```
vertex was not declared in this scope
```

Here's my list of includes from my `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "4x_vertex.h"
#include "4x_constants.h"
```

My `4X_vertex.h`:

```
#ifndef _4X_VERT_H
#define _4X_VERT_H
struct vertex{
        GLfloat x,y,z;
        GLfloat r,g,b;
};
void drawVertexArray(vertex v[]);
vertex* loadVertexData();
#include "4X_vertex.cpp"
#endif
```

The part of `4X_vertex.cpp` that's giving me the trouble:

```
using namespace std;

void drawVertexArray(vertex v[]){
    ... openGL stuff...
}
```

All of this worked before I started moving it around so I'm assuming there's something weird going on with the includes, or something. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You do _not_ include source files (like `4X_vertex.cpp`) in header files. You include header file in source files, and then compile the source file.

Comment: My high school comp-sci teacher led me astray, then. Let me try it that way. (I still include only the header file in my main, though, right?)

Comment: Yes that's right. And in the other source files where you need the structures/prototypes as well.

Comment: Does this also mean I need to duplicate any relevant includes (the SFML stuff) in the 4X_vertex.h file? It's giving me errors when I try to compile vertex.cpp by itself.

Comment: It depends, you can include some needed files (like the one that define the `GLfloat` type) in the header file, and whatever needed in the source file.

Comment: @user1586641 that wouldnt be the first time a comp-sci teacher has led someone astray, and the college teachers can be worse than the hi-school ones

Answer (score 1):

Just some pointers.  Best practice is to divide your project up into multiple source files.  Typically, you would use the word "main" in the file name of the main source file (if applicable). So you might have something like...

```
main.cpp
feature1.cpp
feature2.cpp
tools.cpp
```

For your other files, you will typically name them after the class they implement.  You will most often have both a .h and a .cpp.  Put your declarations in the .h and your definitions in the .cpp had have the .cpp include the .h.  That might give you...

```
main.cpp
feature1.cpp    feature1.h
feature2.cpp    feature2.h
tools.cpp       tools.h
```

The modules that reference one of your classes includes it's .h as well.  So, main.cpp might look like...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "feature1.h"
#include "feature2.h"

using namespace std;
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{ ...
    cout << "Done!\n";
}
```

And feature1.cpp might be...

```
#include "feature1.h"
#include "tools.h"
feature1_class::feature1_class() { ... }
void feature1_class::AUsefulFeature(int val) { ... }
//etc.
```

...where feature1.h declares the class, defined constants, etc. f.g.,

```
#ifndef FEATURE1
#define FEATURE1
#include "tools.h"
class feature1_class
{
public:
    feature1_class();
    void AUsefulFeature(int val);
    int APublicMember;
};
#endif
```

You may have noticed that tools.h is actually include twice in feature1.cpp.  It is included from within the feature1.h and explicitly from the .cpp file.  If you use the following pattern in your .h files  ...

```
#ifndef TOOLS_H
#define TOOLS_H
//... do your thing
#endif
```

... then multiple includes shouldn't cause you any problems.  And as you refactor code, it is one less thing to have to worry about cleaning up.

If you have been using a single file for all your source up till now, you may have been compiling like so...

```
cl main.cpp
```

Which gives you your .exe and .obj and maybe other files.  But with multiple source files involved, it isnt much different.  You can say...

```
cl main.cpp feature1.cpp feature2.cpp tools.cpp
```

There is much more to learn, but this is a start and helps you on the way to better organization of your coding thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include "4X_vertex.h"` at the top of your `4X_vertex.cpp` file. This will allow the `.cpp` file to see the declaration for the `struct vertex`.

In general, each file (both .h and .cpp files) needs to `#include` any header files which contain declarations for items used in that file. This includes the standard headers and OpenGL headers, as well as your custom ones.